# ¿Me pueden ayudar a pulir este codigo?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, radiobutton, radiogroup

Buenas tengo un `RadiogGroup` llamado `rdgroup` y adentro cuatro `RadioButton` llamados `rbtna` `rbtnb` `rbtnc` y `rbtnd` respectivamente, lo que trato de hacer es que al momento de que se escoja uno de los raiobutton busque en mi BD de firebase y muestre si es correcto o no
Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
private DatabaseReference tema;  
---------------------------------  
tema = database.getReference("Temas").child("suma").child("1");
-----------------------------------
--califica es el onclick de mi botón siguiente

public void califica(View view) {
    DatabaseReference obten=tema.child("respuesta");
    if (view.getId()== Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(obten))){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),restaActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

mi bd en firebase es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me aparece el siguiente error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.juegosludicos.vedette-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes17.dex)
```

Comment: El titulo no es muy adecuado para tu pregunta, revisa [ask], de hecho en realidad no es pulir, en realidad no funciona correctamente :(. Por otro lado, esto me parece incompatibilidad en tus dependencias, agrega tu archivo build.gradle por favor.

Comment: como dice @Jorgesys tiene toda la pinta de un problema de compilación/dependencias, tendrias que incluir como minimo la estructura del proyecto y los build.gradle para poder identificar el problema